# adding the values from a method

Tags: java, eclipse, radio-button, addition

I have an application with 8 multiple choice questions, with answers to each question stored in 2 radio buttons. The first radio button has a value called `choice1Value` and the second radio button has a value called `choice2Value`. The reponses are collated in the arrays `choice1ValueArray[]` and `choice2ValueArray[]`. However, the method  `+getTotalRisk()` only take the values from the last question. In fact, it is supposed to take all the values from all the questions (depending upon which radio button was selected) and add them together.

```
private int getTotalRisk() {
        int totalRisk = choice1Value + choice2Value;
        return totalRisk;
    }

    public void submitButtonClicked() {

        if (infoIsValid()) {
            for (int i = 1; i < choice1Array.length; i++) {
                username = "Johnny";
                questionID = i;

                if (choice1Array[i].isSelected()) {
                    answer = choice1Array[i].getText();
                } else if (choice2Array[i].isSelected()) {
                    answer = choice2Array[i].getText();
                }

                QuizAnswer q = new QuizAnswer(username, questionID, answer);

                q.createQuizAnswer();

                if (choice1Array[i].isSelected()) {
                    choice1Value = choice1ValueArray[i];
                }
                else if (choice2Array[i].isSelected()) {
                    choice2Value = choice2ValueArray[i];
                }
                    System.out.println("Risk Value is " + getTotalRisk());

            }
            System.out.println("Your total risk value is " + getTotalRisk());
        }

    }
```

Here is my output of the result when the submit button is clicked. You can see that it shows risk value for each question but when finally at the end, it supposed calculate all the risk value but it still shows 0 (Your total risk value is 0).

```
connection is jdbc:odbc:myHealthDatabase
DB Query: INSERT INTO QUIZANSWER (Username, QuestionID, Answer) VALUES ('Johnny', '1', 'Above 45')
Connection is closed
Risk Value is 1
connection is jdbc:odbc:myHealthDatabase
DB Query: INSERT INTO QUIZANSWER (Username, QuestionID, Answer) VALUES ('Johnny', '2', 'Yes')
Connection is closed
Risk Value is 3
connection is jdbc:odbc:myHealthDatabase
DB Query: INSERT INTO QUIZANSWER (Username, QuestionID, Answer) VALUES ('Johnny', '3', 'Yes')
Connection is closed
Risk Value is 2
connection is jdbc:odbc:myHealthDatabase
DB Query: INSERT INTO QUIZANSWER (Username, QuestionID, Answer) VALUES ('Johnny', '4', 'Yes')
Connection is closed
Risk Value is 3
connection is jdbc:odbc:myHealthDatabase
DB Query: INSERT INTO QUIZANSWER (Username, QuestionID, Answer) VALUES ('Johnny', '5', 'No')
Connection is closed
Risk Value is 2
connection is jdbc:odbc:myHealthDatabase
DB Query: INSERT INTO QUIZANSWER (Username, QuestionID, Answer) VALUES ('Johnny', '6', 'No')
Connection is closed
Risk Value is 2
connection is jdbc:odbc:myHealthDatabase
DB Query: INSERT INTO QUIZANSWER (Username, QuestionID, Answer) VALUES ('Johnny', '7', 'Yes')
Connection is closed
Risk Value is 1
connection is jdbc:odbc:myHealthDatabase
DB Query: INSERT INTO QUIZANSWER (Username, QuestionID, Answer) VALUES ('Johnny', '8', 'Yes')
Connection is closed
Risk Value is 0
Your total risk value is 0
```

Comment: There isn't enough context here to understand what is happening. What does `getTotalRisk()` do? Where are all the fields used in `submitButtonClicked()` declared?

Comment: I have added in the getTotalRisk() method and the submitButtonClicked() is the action performed of the submit button which will then record all the selected radio buttons and calculate the risk values.

Answer (score 1):

arrays are zero based

```
for (int i = 1; i < rArray.length; i++)
```

should probably be

```
for (int i = 0; i < rArray.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not accumulating results as (I think) you intend, you keep overwriting `answer`, `choice1Value` and `choice2Value` each time through your for loop. That's why you're getting the "values from the last question".

But it's hard to answer your question in more detail without knowing more. As casablanca said in the comments, vital information is missing here. What are you trying to do? What is `answer` and how is it used? What are your g/v/r/fArray variables for (you should give them better names by the way)? Can you give an example of what your radio buttons are supposed to add up to?

Edit after your comment: I *think* you need something like this to add up your risk values:

```
public int getTotalRisk() {
  if (!infoIsValid()) {
    return 0;
  }
  int totalRisk = 0;
  // assuming choice1Array.length == choice2Array.length...?
  for (int i = 0; i < choice1Array.length; i++) {
    if (choice1Array[i].isSelected()) {
      answer = choice1Array[i].getText();
    } else if (choice2Array[i].isSelected()) {
      answer = choice2Array[i].getText();
    } // is it possible for neither to be selected?
    QuizAnswer quizAnswer = new QuizAnswer("Johnny", i, answer);
    quizAnswer.createQuizAnswer(); // not sure what this line is meant to do
    if (choice1Array[i].isSelected()) {
      totalRisk += choice1ValueArray[i];
    } else if (choice2Array[i].isSelected()) {
      totalRisk += choice2ValueArray[i];
    } // if one is always selected, make it if/else, not if/else if
  }
  return totalRisk;
}
```

I've taken the liberty to suggest a few changes, feel free to use or ignore them... The point is that in order to get the total risk, you need to keep adding to a variable (`totalRisk`) every time through the for loop so that it keeps increasing by the choice value for each value of `i` (and I've made the loop start at 0, i.e. the first position in the array, as Peter's answer suggested; change this back if there's a valid reason for the loop to start at 1, i.e. at the second position in the array). What you were doing, as mentioned previously, was overwriting the "total" value each time around the loop, so at the end you got whatever the value from the last loop was.

I'll leave it up to you to fit that method in with your code as I don't know what the `createQuizAnswer()` method does, but hopefully you'll get the point about what you were doing wrong. As a final general suggestion, you should probably read up on variable scopes as I think you're not always aware of how to use them.

Comment: I have edited the array name for  better understanding as you requested. Basically, each of my radio button is assigned with the values. Therefore, when a radio button is selected, the assigned value will be taken from that particular selected radio button. When in the end, 8 radio button will be selected altogether as I got 8 questions. Therefore, I want to add those assigned values of each radio button and show the total values.